# what is the standard way to eliminate code redundancy with template class specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I have a template class which recursively build fibonacci array using template recursion like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C++ Helpers/static_check.hpp"
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct valid_type : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_integral<T>::value  > {};

template <size_t N, typename = void>
struct fibonacci {
    static const int value = fibonacci<N - 1>::value + fibonacci<N - 2>::value;
};
template <size_t N>
struct fibonacci <N, typename std::enable_if<(N < 2)>::type > {
    static const int value = 1;
};
template <size_t N, typename T = int>
struct fibonacci_array {
    static_assert(valid_type<T>::value, "invalid storage type for fibonacci sequence");
// the base case specialization should has all general case code except for the next line
    fibonacci_array<N - 1, T> generate_sequence_here;
    int value;
    fibonacci_array() : value(fibonacci<N - 1>::value) {}
    int operator [] (size_t pos) {
        return *((int*)this + pos);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct fibonacci_array<1, T> {
    static_assert(valid_type<T>::value, "invalid storage type for fibonacci sequence");
    int value;
    fibonacci_array() : value(fibonacci<0>::value) {}
    int operator [] (size_t pos) {
        return *((int*)this + pos);
    }
};

int main () {
    const size_t n = 10;
    fibonacci_array<n, int> arr;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

what i want to do is to eliminate code redundancy in the base case specialization (when `N == 1`)
Note: if i partitioned the class members into private and public ones and used direct inheritance, it wouldn't be efficient because the private members are actually get inherited but without access to them.
i'm thinking of creating a base class to make the general template class and the specialization inherit from it, but i don't know the exact syntax for that and if there's nicer way it would be better. thanks!

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about terminating your recursion at `N=0`? In this case you can throw away the whole body for `fibonacci_array<1, T>` and replace with this little guy:

```
template <typename T>
struct fibonacci_array<0, T> 
{
};
```

One pitfall is that this specialization will be empty, but when you aggregate it to the main class as `generate_sequence_here`, it will consume 1 byte of space, since in C++ every object shall have a unique address. This will waste you 1 byte of space (and will require to update your `operator[]`). Don't worry though, it can be easily solved, if you change aggregation of `fibonacci_array<N - 1, T>` to inheritance from it. This works thanks to the feature called "empty base class optimization".

Also, if you can use C++14, prefer constexpr constructors for this task instead, the code will be much cleaner:

```
template <int N, typename T = int>
struct fibonacci_array 
{
    int values[N];
    constexpr fibonacci_array() : values()
    {
        if (N > 1)
            values[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
            values[i] = values[i - 1] + values[i - 2];
    }
    constexpr int operator [] (size_t pos) const
    {
        return values[pos];
    }
};
```

See the [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3da7eb264fdcdda7).

Also see how compiler was able to compute it on compile time: https://godbolt.org/g/kJEFvN

Comment: i don't think the first approach is valid because empty struct has non-zero size so i need to change operator [] details according to that non-zero size.
as for the c++14 approach it's really cool easy one but i need a way using c++11 if possible. thanks

Comment: Did you write this comment before I updated the answer? I addressed this non-zero size problem. As for C++11, I'm pretty sure you will be able to make a one-liner function that generates your sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... I'm not a standard expert... but I find your mode to access to the values

```
    return *((int*)this + pos);
```

a little dangerous.

I suggest to avoid the class recursion, to use a simple `constexpr` function to calculate the values

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T fibonacci (T const & val)
 { return val < T{2} ? T{1} : (fibonacci(val-T{1})+fibonacci(val-T{2})); }
```

and, using a delegating constructor, initialize a `std::array` in a simple class

```
template <size_t N, typename T = std::size_t>
struct fibonacci_array
 {
   static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                 "invalid storage type for fibonacci sequence");

   std::array<T, N> values;

   template <T ... Is>
   constexpr fibonacci_array (std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const &)
      : values{ { fibonacci(Is)... } }
    { }

   constexpr fibonacci_array ()
      : fibonacci_array{std::make_integer_sequence<T, N>{}}
    { }

   T operator [] (size_t pos) const
    { return values[pos]; }

   T & operator [] (size_t pos)
    { return values[pos]; }
 };
```

This solution use `std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_integer_sequence`, so is a C++14 solution; but if you need a C++11 solution, substitute they isn't really difficult.

The full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr T fibonacci (T const & val)
 { return val < T{2} ? T{1} : (fibonacci(val-T{1})+fibonacci(val-T{2})); }

template <std::size_t N, typename T = std::size_t>
struct fibonacci_array
 {
   static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                 "invalid storage type for fibonacci sequence");

   std::array<T, N> values;

   template <T ... Is>
   constexpr fibonacci_array (std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const &)
      : values{ { fibonacci(Is)... } }
    { }

   constexpr fibonacci_array ()
      : fibonacci_array{std::make_integer_sequence<T, N>{}}
    { }

   T operator [] (std::size_t pos) const
    { return values[pos]; }

   T & operator [] (std::size_t pos)
    { return values[pos]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   constexpr std::size_t n { 10U };

   fibonacci_array<n, int> arr;

   for (auto i = 0U; i < n ; ++i )
      std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Mikhail, my `fibonacci()` function could compute with exponenzial complexity.

With the same exponential algorithm, but using static constexpr values in structs, so using memoization (I hope), the following code should avoid exponential complexity.

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, T N, bool = (N < T{2})>
struct fibonacci;

template <typename T, T N>
struct fibonacci<T, N, false>
   : std::integral_constant<T,   fibonacci<T, N-1U>::value
                               + fibonacci<T, N-2U>::value>
 { };

template <typename T, T N>
struct fibonacci<T, N, true>
   : std::integral_constant<T, 1U>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T = std::size_t>
struct fibonacci_array
 {
   static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                 "invalid storage type for fibonacci sequence");

   std::array<T, N> values;

   template <T ... Is>
   constexpr fibonacci_array (std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const &)
      : values{ { fibonacci<T, Is>::value... } }
    { }

   constexpr fibonacci_array ()
      : fibonacci_array{std::make_integer_sequence<T, N>{}}
    { }

   T operator [] (std::size_t pos) const
    { return values[pos]; }

   T & operator [] (std::size_t pos)
    { return values[pos]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   constexpr std::size_t n { 10U };

   constexpr fibonacci_array<n, int> const arr;

   for (auto i = 0U; i < n ; ++i )
      std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: This implementation of `fibonacci()` function will actually compute value with exponential complexity, won't it?

Comment: @Mikhail - Uhmmm... I was counting on memoization but, with functions... maybe you're right. Answer imptoved adding a solution based on classic template metaprogramming. Thanks.